# Limiting IntelliJ IDEA import suggestions on completion

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea

When I type the name of a class which will need to be imported, IntelliJ lovingly pops up with a list of suggestions. However, most of the time those suggestions are things I'd never want to import, especially by accident -- like `java.awt.*`.

Is there a way to prevent the packages I'll never import from appearing in the completion list?

I've scoured the options but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on the IDEA version: Yes.

In 7.0.5 use menu `File -> Settings` choose `Code Completion` and then `Exclude from Import and Completion` and add the package or class that you don't want to have in your suggestions.

In version 8 and version 9 use menu `File -> Settings` type "Auto import" into the search box and use the `Exclude from Import and Completion` box there.

In version 9 you also have the option of adding Classes and Packages to the exclude-list directly from the import suggestions context-menu:

[image]

Comment: Do we know why it disappeared in 8?

Comment: @Benjamin C: well, I don't think it disappeared, I simply have no v8 on my machine so I couldn't describe the how-to. And JetBrains already moved the online help to v9...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure since when this feature exists. It certainly in the upcoming version 9.0:

When the import-popup shows you can navigate from there to two ignore-option. For example when you type List it could be 'ignore java.awt.List from auto-import' and 'ignore java.awt from auto import'

Or you can configure it in the settings: Editor->Auto-Import: There you can add and remove ignored packages and classes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still stuck on v7. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

in `IntelliJ` version 13.* and 14.* to `Excluding Classes from Auto-Import`

**Steps**:

1) [Open the Settings dialog box](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-settings.html), and under the `Editor` node, click `Auto-Import`.

2) On the `Editor | Auto-Import` page, click `+`

3) In `the dialog box` that opens, type the name of the class or a whole package to be excluded [ **in your case** write `java.awt.*` ], and click `OK`.
Use `+` and  `-` to manage the list of classes and packages that `IntelliJ` IDEA shouldn't place to the suggestion list.

4) Apply changes and close the `Settings dialog`.

**For** More information about `Excluding Classes from Auto-Import` See [helping Doc for IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/excluding-classes-from-auto-import.html)