# How to get IntelliJ From making annoying blue popups?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

On Mac OSX running the latest JDK, my IntelliJ  9.0.3 pops up these incredibly annoying and persistent windows:

[image: annoying-intellij]

This stuff compiles and runs fine, the JDK is definitely operational on this machine. It should be a java.util.string, not some other apache string. 
what is this supposed to be, and how do i get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: It's `java.lang.String`, not `java.util.String`. Classes in `java.lang` package are implicitly imported.

Comment: You can tell it not to suggest classes from a package.  This should stop it suggesting packages you don't want. You should be able to do this easily for the options for the popup.

Comment: What's most ANNOYING is that these popups occur. It's fine if there's an error. Underline it and let me click or hover to see the suggestion. But triggering a popup is a shitty UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have not configured the Java SDK that your project is using.

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK, choose one, make sure it doesn't show in red.

Comment: Often times, there are references already included with a directive that intellij can't pick up, e.g. the ones that are present on the server. In this case it's just plain annoying that it offers to 'fix' your xml. See my answer below on how to disable the auto-import feature for XML.

Answer (score 6):

Found it!
In intellij idea 14, go to

settings -> editor -> general -> auto import, and untick 'show import popup', under the java/kotlin/xml/... section.

That will fix it.

Comment: Actually it's not in the XML section, java has one, python has another, etc. But upvoted nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: As previous comment, upvote for getting us in the ballpark, but use the Java section: "Show import popup for"

Comment: I appreciate the information here.  I *do*.  Given that this is the source of the results for typing "intellij idea make the blue popups go away" into google, though, perhaps it would be worthwhile to tweak the answer for correctness?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore certain packages & classes from the import-popup.

See the answer here: [Limiting IntelliJ IDEA import suggestions on completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725812/limiting-intellij-idea-import-suggestions-on-completion)