# Why doesn't Android Studio import android.os.Handler intelligently?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, import, handler

When I use `android.os.Handler`, Audio Studio always suggests that I import `java.util.logging.Handler`, as you can see in the first figure below.

Why doesn't Audio Studio import `android.os.Handler` intelligently? Or let me choose whether to import `android.os.Handler` or `java.util.logging.Handler`? Just like `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. This is shown in the second figure.

Is this a bug of Audio Studio? Or a configuration error on my part?

I do not have 10 reputation to post images, please click the url to see the figures.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Up0w9lE6_8g/VfACqzKsAKI/AAAAAAAAAFw/HMqwI0smpb8/w551-h499-no/3.png

Comment: Hello.. Please put your cursor to word handler and click both ctrl + Enter. It will automatically imported by android studio..!!

Comment: because android studio is not connected to your brain directly and that's why it does not know what `Handler` class you have in your mind

Comment: All  the comments above have flagged as helpful whilst they are not. I have had the same issue on v2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is to be expected, as others have mentioned. There is a way to avoid it though.

You can configure Android Studio to ignore classes that you never want to import (I've personally done so for both the examples you mention.)

See the Stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725812/limiting-intellij-idea-import-suggestions-on-completion) for more information (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ so the same process applies)

Comment: I have imported android.os.Handler manually instead of changing Android Studio's config.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine if it's once or twice, but I like disabling the suggested imports I'm never going to use because otherwise I have to manually select the import hundreds of times a day. Automatic import is much nicer in this way. `Nullable` and `NonNull` are particularly common, and theres 3 variants of each available in the project.

Comment: Oh, I’ll try your way.Thanks.

Comment: I don't know when or why is the android.os.Handler in there. Anyway, removing the package from the exclusion list solves the missing problem of android.os.Handler class in the helper (`Alt`+`Enter`) import list